# Левада-Центр в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

Левада-центр, Левада-Центр, "Левада-центр", "Левада-Центр" - какой из вариантов правильный?

Answer (score 2):

По-русски названия организаций обычно заключают в кавычки, в отличие от английского. "Центр" здесь является частью названия, а не подразумевает один из центров (учреждений). Поэтому правильно будет написать ***"Левада-Центр".***

Answer (score 2):

Я, пожалуй, соглашусь с Википедией: Левада-Центр

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/382634

Кавычки были бы, если б было так:организация "Левада-Центр", т.е. с родовым понятием, тогда это было бы приложение в кавычках, а здесь речь идёт об аналитическом центре Левады, где Левада-фамилия. Можно было бы сказать Левадовский центр аналитиков. В таких названиях обычно только первое слово пишется с большой буквы, остальные со строчной.Так что большая Ц здесь не совсем по правилам, скорее для внешней рекламной изобразительности, но современные тенденции названий сближаются с иноязычными традициями выделять все начальные буквы существительных-названий, так что это веяние времени, что ли.